# how to show or hide information based on if a user is logged in

Tags: php

I am trying to develop a website and I am having issues with trying to hide information based on if a user is logged in.

I am using mysqli as a database and have registered a test user. Unfortunately, when using echo it doesn't change what is seen.

I have this in the header to create the session:

```
<?php
require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
session_start();
 ?>
```

and then after that, I am using this in the index.php to try and show or hide based on if they are logged in:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged in!</p>';
}

else {
echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged out!</p>';
}
 ?>
```

Regardless of what I seem to do it always displays "you are logged in!"

Comment: could you give us the output `var_dump($_SESSION['userid'])` when you're expecting the user to be logged out?

Comment: Combination of `!isset($_SESSION['userid'])` and `You are logged in` seems suspicious. How can the user be logged in when there is no user ID in the session?

Comment: Your syntax is off. The line containing `!isset()` is displaying logged in because there is no session

Comment: Remove the `!` in front of `isset($_SESSION['userid']`, then it checks `is index userid in Session set? Display 'You are logged in.'`. At the moment, it is checking `is userid in Session NOT set? Display 'You are logged in.'` which is wrong from a logical perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a different index in `login.inc.php` and `index.php`. Try this in your `index.php` and it should work:

```
<?php
require 'header.php';
 ?>

<main>
  <div class="wrapper-main">
<section class="section-default">

<?php
print_r($_SESSION);
if (isset($_SESSION['idusers'])) {
echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged in!</p>';
}

else {
echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged out!</p>';
}
 ?>

</section>
</div>
</main>

 <?php
require 'footer.php';
  ?>
```

I tried your code locally and it is working now.

EDIT: I copied my working code from your `index.php`. Just replace it in your `index.php` file.

Comment: I have copied your code straight into the document and it is not working :S 

I think it is just me making mistakes...

if it possible for you to edit the code from the GDrive and comment where you have updated so that I can see what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: I edited this answer. Just copy the code into your `index.php` (delete everything else).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, I have replaced my index.php file and it is still not working? Have you made edits to any other doc?

Comment: Please add `print_r($_SESSION)` to your index.php (right before the `if`) and paste the output here, please. No, I have not changed anything else.

Comment: Array ( [idusers] => [uidusers] => user123 )

Comment: ignore my previous comment - that was because of cache - still states logged out - I have updated the output - the output remains on refresh

Comment: Thanks Johannes! I have managed to figure it out with your help!

I needed to change the `if (isset($_SESSION['idusers']))` to `if (isset($_SESSION['uidusers']))`

Comment: That means that your attribute `idUsers` in your database is empty - a fact no one could know about. But very nice that it is working now!

Answer (score 0):

If you put userId in session then for checking login you should use

```
isset($_SESSION['userid'])
```

also to check $_SESSION['userid'] is not empty use var_dump($_SESSION['userid'])

to set value in session so after start session use

```
 $_SESSION['userid']= $yourId_number;
```

Comment: I have removed the !  from isset($_SESSION['userid'] but now it just states you are logged out and not logged in even after logging in.

How can I ensure that there is a session?

Comment: before if statement use  var_dump($_SESSION['userid']);die; to see inside of session

Comment: Can you post the code that sets the `$_SESSION['userid']` please?

Comment: I have uploaded the files here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NkWC8UbAv0K4aZeseOosNrqtJhx8dm_B?usp=sharing

Comment: in signing or signup use  if (!isset($_SESSION['userid']))
                                               $_SESSION['userid']=$UserId ; (a value here)

Answer (score 0):

In the login file, make sure you are setting the session variable, e.g

```
 <?php
 /* if  All credentials correct */
 if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
 $_SESSION['user_id']= $actual_user_id;
 ?>
```

and In the index file, do the following it will work.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged in!</p>';
}

else {
echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged out!</p>';
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Hussain - I think I have set the session variable, are you able to take a quick look and tell me if I have made a mistake?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NkWC8UbAv0K4aZeseOosNrqtJhx8dm_B?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like you are never setting `$_SESSION['userid']` because it is called `$_SESSION['idusers']` in `login.inc.php`.

Comment: @Johannes - is this not setting the $_session



'else if ($pwdcheck == true) {
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['idusers'] = $row['idUsers'];
          $_SESSION['uidusers'] = $row['uidUsers'];

          header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
          exit();
        }'

Comment: You are checking for `userid` and not `idusers` in index.php - that's wrong. In other words, you should decide if you want to use `idusers` or `userid` as index.

Comment: I have just updated the index.php to match idusers but it is still displaying you are logged out (header shows login=success)

Comment: @Hussain Abid your solution contains one mistake: Your index for the `$_SESSION` array is called `userid` in `index.php` and `user_id` in the code on the top (be aware of the `_`).

Comment: @Antonio if you have added what @Johannes have said, then after that in the index.php try to add `if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();` and see if it works

Comment: @Johannes thanks i have fixed the typo in my solution